# Stata - How to find which columns have non-empty entries for each row

Tags: row, stata

In Stata, I have a dataset like this:

```
obs    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6
1      .     3     .     .     1
2      2     .     .     4     5
3      .     7     .     .     .
4      1     .     1     .     4
```

How can I find all of the columns that have a non "." value in them, by row?

For example, I want to find that:

`obs 1` has  non-empty values for `v3` and `v6`.

`obs 2`  has  non-empty values for `v2`, `v5`, and `v6`.

`obs 3`  has  non-empty values for `v3`.

`obs 4`  has  non-empty values for `v2`, `v4`, and `v6`.

Here is pseudocode of one way that is not efficient at all (I want to find a better, faster way):

1. Create new variables, `v2a` ... `v6a`.  `v2a` will take string value `"v2"` if there is a non-empty value in the row and `0` otherwise.  Do this for all 'a' variables.
2. Concatenate all the `a` variables.

I don't need a new variable per se.  If it just outputted onto the screen, that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not very elegant, but it does the job.

```
clear
input obs v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1 . 3 . . 1
2 2 . . 4 5
3 . 7 . . .
4 1 . 1 . 4
end

gen strL nonmiss=""
foreach var of varlist v2-v6    {
    replace nonmiss=nonmiss+" "+"`var'" if !missing(`var')
}
list nonmiss
```

Comment: Only two notes. **i)** `gen strL ...` presumes availability of Stata 13. `str` is an option for people with Stata < 13. **ii)** ``... if !missing(`var')`` is a general alternative to ``... if `var' != .``

Comment: @Roberto Thanks for the reminder. I wasn't sure how many variables the OP had in mind. `gen str#` should do the job for earlier versions (# indicating the length of the string variable). I'll edit the `!missing` part into the code.

Comment: `gen nonmiss = ""` will create a string variable and its type will be changed if need be. The main issue for anyone on a version < 13 is whether 244 characters are enough. (The limit was even smaller a while back, but I don't come across people using versions before about 8.)